# When reloading the page, the req.session.cookies and req.session.user objects disappear (Nextjs/Expressjs)

Tags: express, next.js, session-cookies

I have already addressed this question earlier, but no one could answer me, I began to analyze further, but still cannot figure out what is the cause of the problem. Please help, I have nowhere else to ask.

On page reload, my middleware runs:

```
export default (req: Request, res: Response, next: Function) => {
    console.log('req.session._ctx.cookies: ', req.session._ctx.cookies);
    console.log('user: ', req.session.user);
}
```

there are several calls, on the second the data disappears:

```
req.session._ctx.cookies:  {
    ...
    sessionID: '42e142d0-25b5-11ec-a3e7-3b00eaad14f0'
}
user: MyUserObject
req.session._ctx.cookies: [Object: null prototype] {}
user: undefined
```

ready to provide configs session.ts, server.ts if required
This problem occurred when switching to another version of Node and Nextjs

Thank you so much for any help!

Comment: Do you persist the session information on the clientside? If it disappears, make sure to store encrypted session data on clientside and send it to server with each request.  What authentication lib do you use? Is it integrated in `nextjs` ?

Comment: I use passportjs, and I store information in redux on the client side, if I understand your question correctly

Comment: Also client side cookies persist fine

Comment: With the provided description i guess the Cookie was just not sent to server again.. But can be a bug on your server too. Hard to tell.
Create a sandbox with minimal client and server code. If you share that, somebody will surely help you. OR your figure it out yourself ^^

Comment: I cannot explain this, but in the process of answering and reading your question again, I realized where the error is, 2 months ago, before preparing a large patch, I really commented out one line, ohhh => params['headers']['cookie'] = Model.context.req.header('Cookie') => params for cross-fetch, 
she does what you said, what a shame to me ...

Comment: No that's fine xD

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237817/discussion-between-silvan-bregy-and-roman-nozhenko).

Comment: Good you found it. cheers^^